# Validating the Receipt: What do we choose under Export Compliance when Submitting?

Tags: app-store-connect, mac-app-store

If I perform a receipt validation in my code (and include the Security framework) following Apple's Documentation, am I required to select YES when asked "Have you added or made changes to encryption features since you last uploaded a binary for this product" during the Export Compliance?

And if so, how do I respond to "Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?"

And finally... if the answer is YES to both those questions, how do I answer, "Does your product qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5 part 2?"

Comment: Apple docs should provide clear enough instructions to walk you through this stage. In any case, receipt validation MAY answer the first question with a yes but I'm not even certain. You should read the exemptions and see if it mentions Apple's code as an exemption. It should, since they already have export compliance for those frameworks.

Comment: I've read the documents on Receipt Validation a few times, and have found nothing (or have missed it).  I've read other places that by simply including Security.Framework you have to answer YES, but have not been able to confirm it anywhere else.  If it's true, then that throws me into a tizzy on how to respond to the final question.

Comment: This probably isn't the place to find export compliance specialists, unfortunately. The question itself is fairly off-topic for Stack Overflow. I've just tried to help as much as I can.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this is off-topic.  This is something that every developer (or at least the majority of the developers) have to face at some point, and yet there's no mention of this anywhere.  It's an extension of the coding process, and a very streamlined part of it.  If people are posting their applications and protecting it using receipts, this should be extensively documented, which it doesn't appear to be.  Or I'm dope-ishly using the wrong search terms to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.apple.com/legal/export.html). The `iOS SDK` and `Mac OS SDK` both have export compliance already, CCATS and all. Please also *follow the links* on the Export Compliance questionnaire, they provide them so you can look at the exemptions yourself and figure out if it is compliant. If all you're using is Apple's frameworks (no custom encryption) though, the only way you could not be exempted is if any of those clauses at the bottom of the page I linked to applies to you, ie:

- You want to sell the software in Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, or Syria
- You intend the product to be used in the design, development, production or use of nuclear, missiles, or chemical and biological weapons and technology and you don't have explicit authorization from the U.S. Government to do this
- You intend to sell to anyone on the U.S. Treasury Department’s list of Specially Designated Nationals or the U.S. Department of Commerce Denied Person’s List or Entity List

*EDIT:* To summarise (including my comment), you should answer YES and YES, then check the exemptions. As far as I can tell, you should meet one of the exemptions if you aren't using any sort of custom encryption, so you should be able to answer YES to the final question. The list above are clauses that would prevent an application using Apple frameworks from being export compliant.

There's also some good info provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18993463/244343) answer, covering [SNAP-R](https://snapr.bis.doc.gov/snapr/) procedures.

Comment: You may also want to check [this](http://blog.theanimail.com/iphone-encryption-export-compliance-for-apps) out, it says in part "Regardless of the source, so even if you only use encryption methods offered by the iPhone OS, your app is subject to export regulation."

Comment: darvids0n, I'm having some trouble following what you're telling me.  The link in your comment seems to be negating your answer.  Also, the links on the Export Compliance questionare during submission sends you to a government site that doesn't seem to be helpful without some extension knowledge on encryption.

Comment: thank darvids0n, appreciated. hopefully this'll help someone else too!